# Why cant I drag and extend right arrow to increase the Partition size?

Tags: 14.04, gparted, partitioning

I want to extend the size of `/dev/sda7` with unallocated space to the right. But I cant drag it to right.

Here is Screenshot:
http://s10.postimg.org/7ghzjk88p/Screenshot_from_2015_06_01_03_05_17.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sda7 is part of extended partition sda2 which is in use.  Boot from a live USB or CD and perform the operation.  You will have to enlarge sda2 as well.

Comment: Can you guide me how can I extend `/dev/sda7`without loosing any data . I have root  allocated  at `/dev/sda6` and `/home` at `/dev/sda7`

Comment: &  I have booted from live CD. Should I extend `sda2`?

Comment: First, back up all important data, in case something goes wrong.  Once booted from CD and the partition is not in use (no key icon) you should be able to resize it by using the gparted gui.  Do sda2 first, then sda7.

Answer (score 1):

Because sda7 is a logical partition of the primary partition sda2; which is completely filled.